# check whether text is given in all all fields of the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I need to take text from fields which have the same class. But when I apply the condition that if field is empty, give an alert, it checks the condition for the first time and ignores all the others as fields are all on the same page with the same class. I cannot have unique classes for every field because the divs are dynamically generated.

Here's my code,

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function(){
        var maintain=$('form input.inputs-field').val ();
        if(maintain == ''){
            alert('Please fill that field');
            return false;
        }
            else{
            $(document).trigger('save-single-answer', {
        answer: $(this).siblings('.inputs-field').val()
            });
        return true;
       }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/ "Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: `val` returns value of the first matched element, you should iterate through the collection and check the values.

Comment: Have you tried using `.each()`? http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to check all the fields. Current you just get the value of first matched element in `maintain`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function () {


    var maintain = $(this).siblings('.inputs-field').val(); //OR $(this).val()

    if (maintain == '') {
        alert('Please fill that field');
        return false;
    } else {
        $(document).trigger('save-single-answer', {

            //here I assume `this` meant button before (in your code)
            answer: maintain
        });
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: the thing is every field has submit button with it, because i have to show one at a time. the page has all divs but one at a time is visible, so every field has its own submit button. do you think each will work then? i dont think so...

Comment: can you post your html in the question.? Atleast the format of button and input

Comment: <div class="group-1" id="group-question-0">
 <div class="question1-wrapper">
  <div class="question-one-container">
   <div class="personal-overview-header">
    <h1>Overview and Background</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2>Where do you live?</h2>
    <form >
     <input type="text" class="inputs-field" placeholder="City" />
     <br />
     <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: <div class="group-1" id="group-question-2">
 <div class="question1-wrapper">
  <div class="question-one-container">
   <div class="personal-overview-header">
    <h1>Overview and Background</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2>How many children do you have?</h2>
    <form >
     <input type="text" class="inputs-field" placeholder="0" />
     <br />
     <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: these are two divs for example

Comment: one form for each div, each form has a text field and a submit button